# Wrong behaviour of FragmentDialog with TimePicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I am creating a dialog with custom view.
One of the component in the view is a TimePicker.
When doing that, the OK+Cancel buttons of the TimePicker take control and the FragmentDialog default button are disable.

This cause a problem since depending on user data I show/hide the TimePicker view and when it is hidden it also hide the OK+Cancel buttons.

It is important to have a custom view, so the user will be able to select all relevant data in a single view.

**Edit - Add image that shows the problem**

[image]

layout.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="1000dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="@string/automatic_backup_type"
                android:textColor="@color/dialog_text_color"/>

            <!-- depending on the selected value here the timePart layout is showed or hide -->
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/automaticBackupType"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_spinner_background"
                android:prompt="@string/automatic_backup_type"
                android:textColor="@color/dialog_text_color"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
        </LinearLayout>

<!-- Some more controls here that are not relevant -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/timePart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/automatic_backup_time"
                android:textColor="@color/dialog_text_color"/>

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

To show the dialog I use the code:

```
new AutomaticBackupConfigurationAlert().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```

The AutomaticBackupConfigurationAlert code:

```
public static class AutomaticBackupConfigurationAlert extends DialogFragment {

    private Spinner    automaticBackupType;
    private View       timePart;
    private TimePicker time;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AutomaticBackupType type;
        Calendar time;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            type = (AutomaticBackupType)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_TYPE);
            time = (Calendar)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_TIME);
        } else {
            type = SettingsHelper.getAutomaticBackupType();
            time = SettingsHelper.getAutomaticBackupTime();
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_automatic_backup, null);

        this.automaticBackupType = view.findViewById(R.id.automaticBackupType);
        this.timePart = view.findViewById(R.id.timePart); // When this is hide, no buttons for OK+Cancel
        this.time = view.findViewById(R.id.time);

        updateVisibility(type);

        {
            // backup type
            ArrayAdapter<AutomaticBackupType> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_spinner_item, AutomaticBackupType.values());
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
            automaticBackupType.setAdapter(adapter);
            automaticBackupType.setSelection(type.ordinal());
        }
        {
            // time
            this.time.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
            this.time.setCurrentHour(time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            this.time.setCurrentMinute(time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        }

        automaticBackupType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AutomaticBackupType tmpAutomaticBackupType = (AutomaticBackupType)automaticBackupType.getSelectedItem();
                updateVisibility(tmpAutomaticBackupType);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.automatic_backup_configuration_title)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do nothing here because we override this button later to change the close behaviour.
                        // However, we still need this because on older versions of Android unless we
                        // pass a handler the button doesn't get instantiated
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, null)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
        if (d != null) {
            Button positiveButton = d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // save the data
            });
        }
    }

    private void updateVisibility(AutomaticBackupType tmpAutomaticBackupType) {
        if (tmpAutomaticBackupType != null) {
            UiHelper.setVisibility(timePart, !tmpAutomaticBackupType.equals(AutomaticBackupType.disabled), true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem you're facing.

Comment: The problem is that if the user select to disable automatic backup, I am hiding the TimePicker component. When I do that the OK and Cancel buttons of the dialog disappear and I cannot confirm or cancel the changes. If I do not use a TimePicker in the view layout there is no problem.

Comment: In the UiHelper.setVisibility() method you just change the visibility of the TimePicker or you do other things as well? Also, why did you use minHeight="1000dp" in your layout file? Judging by the fact that you implement a custom behavior to your dialog(along a custom view) you should probably look into using your own implementation of Dialog instead of the simpler dialog type which is AlertDialog.

Comment: Ion the UiHelper.setVisibility, I simply set the view visibility to gone, not to the TimePicker, but to the contsining latout. The minHeight is used so the dialog will look the same when opened,  regardless to the settings (since for different settings I show/hide different views). I may have to implement something else, but not sure a different dialog will help. To my understanding, it seems that when you use a TimePicker in a dialog, it takes control over the dialog buttons. If I simply remove the TimePicker view from the layout,  the dialog behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution (I do not like it, but it works).

I am posting it here in case someone else will need it.

It seems that TimePicker has the Positive/Natural/Negative buttons with the same id as the AlertDialog. When I set them using the Dialog builder, it actually set the one in the TimePicker.

In general, the solution is to add a view to the Dialog without the TimePicker view and add it only after the buttons are set.

The code above changed in two location:
First in **onCreateDialog** method in the time settings block:

```
{
    // time
    this.time.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    this.time.setCurrentHour(time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    this.time.setCurrentMinute(time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    timePart.removeView(this.time); // remove the TimePicker view from the layout
}
```

Second in the **onStart** method

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
    if (d != null) {
        Button positiveButton = d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        timePart.addView(time); // Now we can add the view
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // save the data
        });
    }
}
```